# ngx-toastr error in loading not found angular firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-toastr

I am trying to use the ngx-toastr. I installed ngx-toastr, imported to the app.module.ts, and added to style in angular.json. I got a complie error after that. The following is the error:

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\hjishe07\Desktop\firebase\node_modules\ngx-toastr\toastr.css' in 'C:\Users\hjishe07\Desktop\firebase\angularfirebasecrud'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a problem with css. As mentioned in the [setup guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#setup) you should try with importing the css file to your angular.json file

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss",
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css" // try adding '../' if you're using angular cli before 6
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the toastr using following commands :

1. `npm install ngx-toastr --save`
2. `npm install @angular/animations --save`

@angular/animations package is a required dependency for the default toastr.

> Learn more about toastr [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr)

Comment: You can refer official link of the toastr(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr)